# Create Permissions plugin (aplugin.*) - Spigot/Bukkit - Java

Tags: java, permissions, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to create something like a little Permissions plugin, but my problem is that I don't know how to give a Player for example the Permissions `aplugin.chat` and `aplugin.color` when I only give him the Permission `aplugin.*`. Of course it is no problem if the Permission is registered and I can check every Permission from `Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPermissions()`. How can I solve it if it isn't registered? In BungeeCord there is a Event where I can see the required Permission, but in Spigot/Bukkit?

Here is my newest version of code for setting the permissions:

```
// setPerms
public static void setPerms(Player p) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement("SELECT Permission FROM Permissions WHERE Gruppe = ?");
        ps.setString(1, User.getPermGroup(p.getName()));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        PermissionAttachment pa;
        if (main.perms.containsKey(p.getName())) {
            pa = main.perms.get(p.getName());
        } else {
            pa = p.addAttachment(plugin);
        }
        while (rs.next() == true) {
            String perm = rs.getString("Permission");
            boolean value = true;
            if (perm.startsWith("-")) {
                perm = perm.substring(1);
                value = false;
            }
            if (perm.endsWith("*")) {
                if (perm.equals("*")) {
                    for (Permission pe : Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPermissions()) {
                        pa.setPermission(pe, value);
                    }
                    pa.setPermission(perm, value);
                } else {
                    String search = perm.substring(0, perm.length() - 1);
                    for (Permission pe : Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPermissions()) {
                        if (pe.getName().startsWith(search)) {
                            pa.setPermission(pe, value);
                        }
                    }
                    pa.setPermission(perm, value);
                }
            }
            pa.setPermission(perm, value);
        }
        main.perms.replace(p.getName(), pa);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: You can't solve it, bukkits permission model is based on that plugins register a permission, and that that permission has children. If you are making up your own system for the missing star, some plugins will bug

Comment: Okay :/ Than thank you :)

Comment: Only one more Question: How is it possible for plugins like PermissionsEx?

Comment: They use `Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPermissions()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this '*' permission by overriding permission checks.
[Info(Click me)](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-override-permission-checks.407679/)

PermissionBase is your class that extends PermissibleBase that override the hasPermission methods.

Simply use the reflection in the thread to set any player's PermissibleBase to yours allowing you to override bukkit's permission checks.

This will override bukkit meaning all other plugins will follow the same rules in your PermissionBase(Or whatever you name it) class.

***For*** ***'plugin.*'*** >

To create a 'plugin.*' permission you will have to get all permission of said 'plugin'only enabling access if the checked permission is in said plugin AND said user has permission 'plugin.*'.

This will simply give the user access to all of a plugins permission ONLY if your system knows said permission is said plugins permission and if user has access to all of the plugins permission('plugin.*') allow access no matter what.

Comment: It is working very well <3 I think now my smile is too big for my face ;D

Comment: @Nightfighter001 Oh mine was too when I figured this out myself. NO one gave me an awnser I just like using reflection and came up with an idea. _My face expanded just to fit my smile ;-;_

Comment: @Nightfighter001 I plan to do somthing like this to add logic to player pushing in 1.9 So if you ever need to disable it for parkour or somthing I'm already trying to come up with an idea.

Comment: @Nightfighter001 Also please try to set the question as accepted for all questions I've awnsered that you well like the most. I'm kinda stuck question banned and trying to get out. ;C

Comment: I think maybe now I have a Little Problem... This is the class I created, but WorldEdit doesn't want to work with it anymore... Here is my class: http://pastebin.com/G0YnNP3g What sould I Change in the Code?

Comment: @Nightfighter001 Lets create a bukkit conversation to solve this.